# lm-sensors ubuntu 14.04 core voltages

Tags: 14.04, kernel, performance, lm-sensors

I am trying to measure the core voltages of my cpu. I installed the lm-sensors, I ran the sensors-detect and I reply YES to all of the question. At the end of the sensors-detect I get:

```
To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!
Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)y
Successful!
Monitoring programs won't work until the needed modules are
loaded. You may want to run 'service kmod start'
to load them.
Unloading i2c-dev... OK
Unloading i2c-i801... OK
Unloading cpuid... OK
```

when I run: "sudo service kmod start" I get: kmod stop/waiting

When I type sensors after these I can't find the core voltages. I only get the temperatures. Any ideas?

Comment: You may be able to find the voltage your mainboard is feeding your CPU on one of your BIOS pages

Comment: Different motherboards and chipset wil require radically different drivers, many of which wont be available (likely as manufacturers may not make this obvious for developers making the drivers)! See also https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lm_sensors#Troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

what version of lm-sensors are you using? what kind of chipset/board are you using? If I had to guess I would say the version of lm-sensors you have does not fully support your board, if you are not running the latest version, remove current version, install latest, and redo sensors-detect, then reboot (I know you can just restart service but it's less complicated just to tell a user to reboot, leaves less room for user error). If you are not running the latest chances are the newest version will improve on your current situation, but that does not mean its fully supported.

Here is latest version as of 09/18/2014 [3.3.5](http://www.lm-sensors.org/wiki/Download) also 2 recomended patches for the release, [r6216](http://www.lm-sensors.org/changeset/6216), and [r6237](http://www.lm-sensors.org/changeset/6237).